# Automatically run as a different user, using the special interface

Tags: authentication, user, runas, windows-authentication

I want to run a program as a different Windows user, protected by a password. Now, in my company, there is a single-sign-on system where if you can enter a PIN attached to your email, it will authenticate you as this other Windows user. This SSO PIN authentication method is offered via a standard Windows dialog (not customized in any visible way), and it is offered at Windows logon (if logging on with said user) and in multiple other situations where authentication is required (if not logged on with said user).

If I do the "UI" method to do this, I press Shift down, right-click on my program, select "Run as different user", and get the SSO PIN interface prompt via the seemingly standard Windows dialog.

However when trying this from the command line, like this :

```
runas /user:NETWORK\<username> path/to/program.exe
```

instead of the special interface to enter my SSO PIN, I get the following prompt in the command line window :

```
Enter the password for NETWORK\<username>:
```

if I enter the password I get what I want, but - why is it circumventing the PIN thing ? How to circumvent the circumventing ? Or more generally, how to easily automate opening the program as the user using the SSO PIN process, especially at startup ?

Comment: That's hard to answer without knowing the SSO and your internal network architecture. Why don't you ask your IT people?

Comment: Fair enough actually, but I am not sure that they will give me an answer, what I am doing is definitely non-standard.

Comment: What does the SSO dialog look like – is it just the built-in Windows credential dialog (with password/PIN/etc options), or is it customized? In general your description doesn't sound like any special system, it sounds like you're getting authenticated as the other user literally because you used "Run as another user" and entered *that other user's* own PIN.

Comment: Yes, it's a standard Windows dialog, not customized in any visible way - but I see my email and a prompt for a PIN in there (and also standard options to enter any other Windows user I like). And this dialog is what I don't see if I use `runas` in the command line.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like it's regular central logon through either Active Directory or Azure AD, both of which use account names shaped just like email addresses (though they're not necessarily the same thing as an email address; they're just in the same user@domain format). _(dsregcmd /status would tell you which one it is, though it doesn't really matter here.)_

Comment: Well, not to go too far down a rabbit hole / tangent : the "computer network" domain name is slightly different than the "email" domain name that we use, but it's still my email that shows up for authentication. As for wether it is Azure AD or Active Directory that is used - no idea, I would rather suggest Evidian Enterprise SSO as it says this in multiple other places, but still - why no reaction from that when in CMD ?

Answer (score 0):

> why is it circumventing the PIN thing

It's not "circumventing" anything that wasn't mandatory to use in the first place. Unlike with e.g. "Run as administrator" UAC elevation prompts (where the program can only *request* the prompt but the OS is in control of displaying it), in the "Run as *user*" case it's the program itself that is responsible for displaying whatever credential prompt it wants.

(This is possibly because the "Run as another user" functionality predates UAC by a decade, and MS haven't reworked it to use UAC's secure prompts.)

So here it's the graphical shell/file manager (Explorer) itself that collects credentials and sends them to the Secondary Logon service. Since `runas` doesn't rely on Explorer but talks directly to the Secondary Logon service, it doesn't get to use Explorer's UI either.

Meanwhile the `-Verb` option in PowerShell's Start-Process *does* go indirectly through Explorer (using ShellExecute), which accepts the `RunAsUser` verb for the "Run as another user" function:

```
Start-Process -Verb RunAsUser notepad.exe
```

(The "Run as administrator" item corresponds to the `RunAs` verb.)